# Обновление данных таблицы при изменении значения поля количества товаров!

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Пишу самостоятельно интернет магазин с нуля. Начал писать корзину и столкнулся с проблемой...

Есть корзина с полями:

товар 1 количество штук 1 стоимомть 333р
товар 2 количество штук 1 стоимомть 343р
товар 3 количество штук 1 стоимомть 353р

Замысел: Сделать так, чтобы при изменении поля "количество штук" (только его и можно изменить) автоматически обновлялась запись о количестве штук в БД.

Как это сделать?

Если поле "количество штук" имеет разное значение id, т.е.

```
<input name="quantity" id="quantit1" class="quantity" type="text" value="1" />
<input name="quantity" id="quantit2" class="quantity" type="text" value="1" />
<input name="quantity" id="quantit3" class="quantity" type="text" value="1" />
```

Помогите с решением задачи!

Comment: атрибут **name** должен иметь разные значения. Можно повесить отправку AJAX на событие onchange. Не очень будет красиво, конечно

Comment: Как тогда решить проблему с распознанием в файле обработчике, что это пришло quantity1 или quantity2

Comment: Сериализуешь форму и отправляешь GET-ом например, а на PHP ловишь. Я не силен в PHP, кажется массив $_GET  за это отвечает. И там будет $_GET['quantity1 '] или как то так, вам виднее .))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В корзине у вас должны быть (*по идее*) строки, где указывается наименование товара, кол-во, цена и сумма для каждой позиции поотдельности. Предположим, что выводите вы эти строки в табличном варианте. Тогда тег <tr> может служить "хранилищем" id товара, данные которого, вам и надо обновить, если изменено количество заказываемого товара. В качестве "хранилища", можно использовать id для каждой строки или любой удобный атрибут (смотреть по ситуации). Но я предпочел бы использование атрибута [data-*](http://habrahabr.ru/post/139210/).

Ясное дело, что вы лучше знаете, каие данные вам нужны для обновления, но думаю, что [мой простой примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3UKXn/5/), в общих чертах, натолкнет вас на путь истинный ;)

P.S. С полученными данными, в php-обработчике работаете, как с многомерным массивом.

**UPD**

как передаются данные - можно глянуть с помощью [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/) или сделайте следующее:

- Изменяем $.ajax

  ```
  $.ajax({
     url: 'handler.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {refreshData : itemsData},
      success: function(response){
          if(response){
              $('#res').html(response); // на странице должен быть какой-нибудь элемент с id = res
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- В файле **handler.php**, прописываете такой код:

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['refreshData']) && !empty($_POST['refreshData'])){
      $refreshData = $_POST['refreshData'];
      $respons = '';
      for($i = 0; $i < count($refreshData); $i++){
          $respons .= '<ol>';
          foreach($refreshData[$i] as $key => $val){
              $respons .=  '<li>'.$key.' = '.$val.'</li>';
          }
          $respons .= '</ol>';
      }
      echo json_encode($respons);
      exit;
  }
  ```

А дальше, я надеюсь, что логика вас не подведет ;)

Comment: вы мне дали прям спасение, а то я там такого быдлокода накрутил, но работает... =) попробую разобраться в вашем коде - спасибо, за путь истинный =)

Comment: пардоньте за совсем наглость не пойму как в php обработчике распознать данные переданные скриптом?

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, дополнил в ответе.

Comment: благодарю, куда можно будет перевести - "спасибо"? желательно яндекс

Answer (score 0):

То, что name должен быть разным - факт.
В php есть замечательный цикл foreach($array AS $key=>$value){}
Т.е. передаём ajax`ом поля

```
data:{
item_1:it1Count,
item_2:it2Count,
item_3:it3Count,
...
}
```

и циклом foreach на php разбираете массив $_POST

```
foreach($_POST AS $k => $v){
    mysqlquery = "UPDATE ~tabname~ SET ~itemcount~ = '".$v."' WHERE ~itemname~ = '".$k."'";
    ...
}
```

где 
~ - одинарная косая ковычка, которая почему-то тут не ставится
itemcount - имя колонки "кол-во товаров" в таблице
itemname - имя колонки "название товара" в таблице